# Complex number (Finding polar representation)

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $$z= 1- i \sqrt 3$$
Find polar representation of $$iz^-2$$
I have a solution but the solution given me seems to be different from what I get. 
What I got: $$1/4 e^{-i5/6 \pi}$$ while the solution gives 
$$2 e^{i1/6 \pi}$$

Not sure how I went wrong, any advice?

EDIT: My workings.

I'm not sure which part of my working went wrong, so I'm just going to list out my workings:

$$\begin{aligned}z=1-i\sqrt {3}\\ \left| r\right| =\sqrt {4}=2\\ \arg \left( z\right) =-\dfrac {\pi }{3}\\ z=2e^{i\dfrac {\pi }{3}}\\ i=e^{i\dfrac {\pi }{2}}\\ iz^{-2}=\dfrac {i}{z^{2}}\end{aligned}$$
$$\dfrac {i}{z^{2}}=\dfrac {1}{2^{2}}\left[ ( \cos \left( \dfrac {\pi }{2}-2\left( \dfrac {\pi }{3}\right) \right) +i\sin ( \dfrac {\pi }{2}-2\left( \dfrac {\pi }{3}\right) \right]$$

That's how I got my argument and new angle.

Comment: It would help in finding out exactly where you went wrong if you typeset your working out in the question :)

Comment: Is that supposed to be $iz^{-2}$ or $i\overline{z}^2$? If the former, the magnitude should be $1/$. If the latter, the magnitude will be $4$. I don't see an interpretation, where the magnitude would be $2$, so the given solution is suspect unless the question is mistranscribed.

Comment: Posting my working in the main post

Comment: It looks to me like you calculated $(iz)^{-2}$ while you were asked to calculate $i(z^{-2}$.  Multiply by i after raising to the power, not before.

Comment: Wouldn't $$(iz)^-2$$ have the modulus equals to $$\frac{1}{(2^2)(1)}$$ which is the same? Sorry I didn't really catch your part